# find example of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Q: let $n \geqslant 3$, find an example of linear transformation $T: R^n \to R^n$ that $Im \cap ker T =\{0\}$

and that $\text{ker}\ T=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) | x_1+x_2+...+x_{n-2}=0 \}$.

I'm pretty sure I know how to solve it for $n=3$ but I'm not sure how to solve it for $n\geqslant3$. any advises on how to approach this one?

Comment: How do you solve it in case $n=3$? What's a problem you face in case $n=4$?

Comment: @Taro it's not specifically for $n=4$, I find it hard to express the solution for any $n$

Comment: @Taro I can edit my quesiton with the solution to $n=3$ if that could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion:
$$ T := \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0
\end{bmatrix}_{n \times n}$$

Answer (score 1):

How about $$T:(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1+\dots+x_{n-2},x_1+\dots+x_{n-2}, \dots,x_1+\dots+x_{n-2})$$